# Basic classification in tensorflow tutorial

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I just started learning tensorflow and am working on the basic classification tutorial in their official page.

[Basic Classification Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification)

From the below piece of code

```
def plot_image(i, predictions_array, true_label, img):
predictions_array, true_label, img = predictions_array[i], true_label[i], img[i]
plt.grid(False)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])

plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.binary)

predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions_array)
if predicted_label == true_label:
color = 'blue'
else:
color = 'red'

plt.xlabel("{} {:2.0f}% ({})".format(class_names[predicted_label],
                            100*np.max(predictions_array),
                            class_names[true_label]),
                            color=color)

def plot_value_array(i, predictions_array, true_label):
predictions_array, true_label = predictions_array[i], true_label[i]
plt.grid(False)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
thisplot = plt.bar(range(10), predictions_array, color="#777777")
plt.ylim([0, 1])
predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions_array)

thisplot[predicted_label].set_color('red')
thisplot[true_label].set_color('blue')
```

The below are the sample results of the test data.

**Case 1:**

[image: Test Case1]  [image: Models]

**Case 2**

[image: Test Case2]  [image]

Even though the system predicted it with 100%, then why did it displayed the results with the red color?

In the predicted label, it is not showing any other classes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the code.

- "i" will for predictions_array, take the first array element(which is an array). This part is ok, but it is always going to be index 0 you need for the prediction array. Two ways to fix this: either pass it as "predictions_array[0]" when calling like I did below. Or modify the function to include "predictions_array = predictions_array[0]"
- Since "i" must be 0 for the predictions array it will in the original code always check test_labels[0]. This will then for all cases when you predict something else than 9 give a red (since it thinks its a wrong prediction). Therefore passing i as the index of the test image will give you the correct label.

Suggestion of a modified function:

```
def plot_value_array(i, predictions_array, true_label):
  print(true_label)
  true_label = true_label[i]
  plt.grid(False)
  plt.xticks([])
  plt.yticks([])
  thisplot = plt.bar(range(10), predictions_array, color="#777777")
  plt.ylim([0, 1])
  predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions_array)

  thisplot[predicted_label].set_color('red')
  thisplot[true_label].set_color('blue')
```

And modified calling where "1" is the image I am in this case testing (**make this a variable so you dont have to type it twice when testing**).
In other words: in case img = test_images[1]  I have to pass 1 to the function.

```
plot_value_array(1, predictions_single[0], test_labels)
plt.xticks(range(10), class_names, rotation=45)
plt.show()
```